# Executing VBA shortcut issue

Tags: vba, excel

I used to press "Alt + F8" and I used to see macro window with list of Macros to execute. 
  But from yesterday when I press "Alt + F8" Macro windows pops up with below issues :
  1) "Run/Edit/Delete" button on Macro window is disabled. Only Create Button is active

I have 4 macros in that VBA, out of 4 for 3 I am seeing this problem, for last macros "Run/Edit/Delete" all buttons are enabled.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: This can occur if you duplicate the sub procedure names; it may also indicate a corrupt VBA project.